# Можно ли в vim заменить Esc на сочетание клавиш?

Tags: vim, клавиатура, linux

Заметил, что в vim часто приходится нажимать на Esc для перехода между режимами. Можно ли Esc заменить в данном случае на сочетание клавиш?

Comment: См. :map, :imap и остальные

Answer (score 5):

Вообще я лично пользуюсь сочетанием клавиш jj.

Добавте это в ваш .vimrc

```
" exit to normal mode with 'jj'
inoremap jj <ESC>
```

Это хак используют сотни vimer'ов, просто посмотрите на .dotfiles репозитории на github.com. Причина очень проста, вы постоянно держите палец на кнопке j для навигации по тексту. А для нажатия любой другой кнопки вам потребуется переместить палец. Попробуйте ;)

Answer (score 3):

Есть ещё встроенные Ctrl+C, Ctrl+[.

Если всё равно хочется своё, используй :map

Comment: Ctrl+C  очень удобное, юзаю очень часто.

Answer (score 1):

Еще если используется vim в терминале, то дефолтное поведение терминала часто такое: alt+буква посылает `<ESC>`, затем букву. Так можно одновременно выйти из insert-mode и сделать следующее действие.